# Is it possible to implement a REJECT in abap OO?

Tags: oop, abap

Is it possible to implement the idea below? The idea is that it works pretty much as a [REJECT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapreject.htm) from the [GET](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget-.htm) statement, but inside the OO paradigm.

```
start-of-selection

    lv_max_lines = class1->get_max_lines( ).

    do lv_max_lines.
        class2->method1( class1->get_line_by_index( sy-index ) ).
    enddo.


class 2 implementation.

    method method1.
        method2( is_line ).
    endmethod.

    method method2.
        method3( is_line ).
    endmethod.

    method method3.
        if ls_line <> what_I_need.
            class1->reject( ). "or
            class1->reject( is_line ).
            "go back straight to start of selection and execute next iteration,
            "ignoring the rest of method3 and metho2 and method1 from class2.
        endif.
        "more process
    endmethod.

endclass.
```

Surely it can be done with multiple conditions in class2 methods and `return` statements, but the idea would be to simulate a reject which doesn't require the class2 to have any modifications, the whole job would be left to class1 to handle.

One idea I had was to delete the current line from the class1 table that is being accessed, that would not work as expected, in fact, I am not sure how this would work.

I think this is not possible to achieve, but I'd like to give it a try regardless.

Comment: In OO, the "reject" (kind of jump) could be simulated using [class-based exceptions](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexceptions.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through [class-based exceptions](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexceptions.htm) inheriting from class `CX_NO_CHECK`.

```
" inherit cx_no_check to let the exception bubble upwards
" without having to redeclare it
class bad_input definition inheriting from cx_no_check.
endclass.

start-of-selection

  lv_max_lines = class1->get_max_lines( ).

  do lv_max_lines times.
    try.      
        class2->method1( class1->get_line_by_index( sy-index ) ).
      catch bad_input.
        " do nothing, just continue with the next line
    endtry.
  enddo.

class class2 definition.
  public section.
    methods method1 importing is_line type whatever.
  private section.
    methods method2 importing is_line type whatever.
    methods method3
      importing
        is_line type whatever.
endclass.

class class2 implementation.

  method method1.
    method2( is_line ).
  endmethod.

  method method2.
    method3( is_line ).
  endmethod.

  method method3.
    if ls_line <> what_I_need.
      raise exception new bad_input( ).
    endif.
    "more process
  endmethod.

endclass.
```

Comment: I edited the post: a CX_NO_CHECK class cannot be entered behind the RAISING word.

Comment: Ah, thanks - of course. That’s what happens when you notepad the code instead of compiling it...